# Ursina Engine textures

Tags: python, ursina

So I started playing with an API for python called Ursina Engine and I got to the point I need to add a texture. Whatever I put for the file path, always just doesn't render. No errors, just a blank entity.

```
    from ursina import * # import everything we need with one line.
#an entity is basically anything you can see or hear/interact on a screen

def update():#updtes every frame
    if held_keys['a']:
        test_square.x -= 1 * time.dt #so the .x is the axis (you can use y too and -= minuses every frame), multiplying it by time.delta means it will move in accordance with the framerate
    # time.dt is the completion time between the last frame
    if held_keys['d']:
        test_square.x += 1 * time.dt
app = Ursina()

test_square = Entity(model = 'quad', color = color.red, scale = (1,4), position = (3,1))#x then y for scale and pos

sans_texture = load_texture('sans.png')
sand = Entity(model = 'quad', texture = sans_texture)

app.run()
```

Comment: Is the texture loaded correctly? Where is sans.png located relative to your code?

Answer (score 4):

Your code should work but if it doesn't you probably haven't loaded the texture properly. If it's located in a file called 'textures' for example, your code should be something like this:

```
sans_texture = load_texture('textures/sans.png')
sand = Entity(model = 'quad', texture = sans_texture)
```

But if it still doesn't work, you can try this:

```
sand = Entity(model = 'quad', texture = 'textures/sans.png')
```

I Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the texture isn't loaded correctly, to load it correctly you can try to copy paste the image link, for example:

```
sand = Entity(model = 'quad', texture = 'C:/Users/guest/Pictures/sans.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it :

```
from ursina import * # import everything we need with one line.
#an entity is basically anything you can see or hear/interact on a screen

def update():#updtes every frame
    if held_keys['a']:
        test_square.x -= 1 * time.dt #so the .x is the axis (you can use y too and -= minuses every frame), multiplying it by time.delta means it will move in accordance with the framerate
    # time.dt is the completion time between the last frame
    if held_keys['d']:
        test_square.x += 1 * time.dt
app = Ursina()

test_square = Entity(model = 'quad', color = color.red, scale = (1,4), position = (3,1))#x then y for scale and pos

sand = Entity(model = 'quad', texture = 'sans.png')

app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

So let’s say I have a texture called Example.png, I would include the texture like this

texture=“Example”

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in an assets folder just next to the py file

```
Sand=Entity(model="quad",texture="assets/sans.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead-

```
Sand = Entity(
 model = "quad",
 texture = ("folder_name/sans.png")
)
```

Or if the texture is not in a folder-

```
Sand = Entity(
     model = "quad",
     texture = ("sans.png")
    )
```

Also make sure that the png/texture is in the project folder your working on!

Answer (score 0):

```
from ursina import *

data_mesh = ("\\project\\data\\mesh\\") # the absolute path to the mesh file
data_texture = ("\\project\\data\\mesh\\texture\\") # the absolute path to the texture file

class MyGame(Ursina):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        MyMesh()

class MyMesh(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(model=data_mesh+"name.obj",     # loading the object and texture
                         texture=data_texture+"name.jpg")
app = MyGame()
app.run()
```

To make your work easier, you can create an object loading function by specifying the file index in advance. It is useful in cases when you load a large number of objects, or to create animations.

```
def LMesh(obj="", skin=""):
    lod = Entity(data_mesh+obj+".obj", # Creating paths to grid and texture files by first specifying file indexes (.obj, .jpg)
                 texture=data_texture+skin+".jpg")
```

Now, when calling the function, it is enough to specify the name of the mesh and texture file.

```
LMesh("name_mesh", "name_texture") # Without file index
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. Thanks